# Python command not found error for only one file

Tags: python

I have a flutter project where I am trying the `translation` feature as I am new to it. the code works for most of the files but only the below code have the issue where I am using a `python` script to convert `json` to `arb` file. there is a script where `arb` to `json` is created and its working fine.

the beginning of both the file is same but this one gives error and other one runs fine...

below is the file

```
import json, glob, os, collections
from collections import OrderedDict

folder_path = 'lib/l10n/arb/'
json_folder_path = 'lib/l10n/json/'

for jsonFileName in glob.glob(os.path.join(json_folder_path, 'intl_*.json')):
    with open(jsonFileName, 'r+') as json_file:
        currentJson = json.load(json_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        arbName = jsonFileName.split('/')[-1].replace('json','arb')
        arbFileName = os.path.join(folder_path, arbName)
        with open(arbFileName, 'r+') as arb_file:
            currentArb = json.load(arb_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
            for item in currentJson:
                currentArb[item] = currentJson[item]
            arbString = json.dumps(currentArb, indent=2)
            arb_file.seek(0)
            arb_file.write(arbString)
            arb_file.truncate()
```

error code:

```
scripts/localization/json_to_arb.py: line 1: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/collections
scripts/localization/json_to_arb.py: line 4: folder_path: command not found
scripts/localization/json_to_arb.py: line 5: json_folder_path: command not found
scripts/localization/json_to_arb.py: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
scripts/localization/json_to_arb.py: line 7: `for jsonFileName in glob.glob(os.path.join(json_folder_path, 'intl_*.json')):'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a UNIX based OS, you must add the following line at the very beginning:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That didn't worked for me. Plus as I have stated that the other file works well and starting on both the files are same. so if that  the above case was the issue, I would have errors on both the files and not only this one.